# Trouble with removeAt() due to collisions

Tags: c#, xamarin, monogame

I posted yesterday asking for help about the collisions between two instances in game, the enemies and bullets.

The solution was:

```
foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
    foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)
        if (bullet.boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.boundingBox)) 
        { 
            score += 1;
        }
```

And of course this worked score wise, as I now gain a point every time a bullet intersects with an enemy. The problem occurs when I need to destroy both objects (not all, just the ones that have intersected). My first thought was to use the removeAt() function like so:

```
if (bullet.boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.boundingBox)) 
    { 
        score += 1;
        removeAt();
    }
```

But of course this wouldn't work because generally it's used with an index such as "removeAt(i)". I then tried taking the whole chunk of code that I referenced up the top, and placing it inside both lists like so:

```
for (int i = bullets.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    bullets[i].Update(delta);   

    //Bullets being destroyed upon leaving 
    if (bullets[i].position.Y < 0)
            bullets.RemoveAt(i);

    foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)
            if (bullet.boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.boundingBox)) 
            { 
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
            }
}
```

The game will run at this point, but crash as soon as the bullet collides with the enemy. An error "System.InvalidOperationException" is thrown at the "foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets) line.

I honestly don't know where I should go from here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: This code looks like it will work if you remove one line: `foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)`. Remove that, and watch it run exactly as you originally intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this would be because you are removing elements from `bullets` while you are enumerating over it.  See this:

```
for (int i = bullets.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

You store the count of bullets in i, and decrease it every time.  Then you have two places in your code where the logic removes bullets, thus changing the count of `bullets`.  You are never supposed to modify an array you are enumerating over.

As to a possible solution, you could do exactly what Jason in the comments pointed out.  Add a `bool Delete` property to your class, then instead of calling `RemoveAt`, set the `Delete` flag to true.  The code would look like this:

```
for (int i = bullets.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    bullets[i].Update(delta);   

    //Bullets being destroyed upon leaving 
    if (bullets[i].position.Y < 0)
    {
        bullets[i].Delete = true;
    }

    foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
    {
        if (bullets[i].boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.boundingBox)) 
        { 
            bullets[i].Delete = true;
        }
    }
}

bullets.RemoveAll(b => b.Delete);
```

Comment: When the bullets leave the screen I get the same error I was receiving before on your "foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets) line?

Comment: @phantom I'm literally about to throw my laptop through the window. Why doesn't this work! I really appreciate your help here, because I'm useless. I'm still getting an error on exactly the same line. It's doing my head in.

Comment: @PaulP Send me a pastebin with some/all of the surrounding code...based on the small amount from the question I can't really tell what the error could be.

Comment: @PaulP This would be much easier solved via chat but unfortunately you don't have enough rep yet :(

Comment: @phantom That foreach loop used to delete the bullets will generate `InvalidOperationExceptions` as your removing items from the collection you are enumarating against.

Comment: @MattR Ouch.  Yes true.

Comment: This answer looks like it would work if the whole delete flag thing was removed. A simple `bullets.RemoveAt(i)` should work find under the intersection test. As @MattR said, the removal in the `foreach` will just cause the same error.

Comment: @phantom Looks good! Another way would be to use LINQ: `bullets.RemoveAll(b => b.Delete);`

Comment: @MattR True, but I have a feeling that might be a *bit* too complex right now!

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but you're creating a new bullets list every time this runs, and it looks like code that would run every frame. I'm not a premature optimizer, but I feel that I should advise against this. You're already going through the bullets list backwards, and you're using a counter instead of an enumerator; doing these two things together are the trick that make it possible a simple RemoveAt() call within the original loop.

Comment: @rileywhite Won't a `RemoveAt()` throw off the counter and get wrong results though?

Comment: If the counter was going forward, it would cause incorrect results unless you also decremented the counter. If I'm on the 5th item, and I'm going to look at the 6th item next, then removing the 5th makes the previous 6th the new 5th. But if I'm going to look at the 4th next, then I don't care what happened with the 6th, 7th, 8th, etc. items.

Comment: @rileywhite What about now, as per Matt's solution, I updated it to be `RemoveAll()`, no new object is being created.

Comment: You. Are. Amazing. Thank you so much @phantom for all your help today, I really appreciate it! I'll try and get in touch with you sometime next week and see if I can sort out some way to reward you for your help. Cheers

Comment: Alright that's resolved, thanks Matt and Riley!  No problem @PaulP, happy to help!

Comment: This solution will definitely work, as would the previous solution. The Linq statement removes the extra list creation. It does still add an extra list traversal, but that may or may not be important to you.

Comment: @rileywhite Yeah true.  Apparently the OP is satisfied so it's probably fine.  And yeah sorry for being dense I haven't done C# in years...

Answer (score 0):

Often, I prefer to maintain a new collection for objects to be removed, and then remove them after processing is complete. I find it easy to follow and doesn't have the questionable addition of a control property. Similar to this....

```
List<Bullet> expiredBullets = new List<Bullet>();

for (int i = bullets.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  bullets[i].Update(delta);

  if (bullets[i].position.Y < 0)
  {
    expiredBullets.Add(bullets[i]);
  }
}

foreach(Bullet expiredBullet in expiredBullets)
{
  bullets.Remove(expiredBullet);
}
```